How can I cause a page refresh on form submission with Next.js server actions?
I'm writing a simple form that updates some information for a rendered page, and I want to refresh the page to display the new data once my Next.js server action successfully updates my backend. However, I can't seem to get this to work. My Next version is 14.2.9.
actions.ts
'use server'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

export async function uploadChangedEventDetails(eventId: number, formData: FormData) {
    const rawFormData = {
        title: formData.get('title'),
        description: formData.get('description')
    }
    console.log(rawFormData)

    try {
        // post the changed data (this works. I've truncated the api string here)
        let data = await fetch(`http://.../events/${eventId}`, 
            {
                method: "PATCH", 
                cache: 'no-store',
                body: JSON.stringify(rawFormData)
            }
        )
        let json = await data.json()
        console.log(json)
        
        
    } catch (e) {
        return {message: `Unable to update event with ID: ${eventId}`}
    }
    revalidatePath("/");
    redirect(`/events/${eventId}`)
    

components.tsx
'use client'
import { useState } from "react"
import { Event } from "../types"
import { uploadChangedEventDetails, uploadPhoto } from "./actions"

export function EventDetails({ eventData }: { eventData: Event }) {
    const [editing, toggleEditing] = useState(false)

    if (editing) {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={(e) => {toggleEditing(!editing)}}>Edit</button>
                <EventDetailsForm eventData={eventData} />
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={(e) => {toggleEditing(!editing)}}>Edit</button>
                <h1 className="text-4xl">{eventData.title}</h1>
                <p>{eventData.description}</p>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
function EventDetailsForm({ eventData }: { eventData: Event }) {
    const uploadChangedEventDetailsWithId = uploadChangedEventDetails.bind(null, eventData.id)
    
    return (
        <form action={uploadChangedEventDetailsWithId} className="flex flex-col gap-y-2 border-black border-2 rounded-lg p-2">
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" defaultValue={eventData.title} />
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" defaultValue={eventData.description} />
            <input className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-2 cursor-pointer" type="submit" value="Submit Changed Event Details" />
        </form>
    )
}

I've tried my server action (uploadChangedEventDetails) with and without the try-catch, but neither successfully causes a page refresh. My approach is based off of Next.js' Routing Docs

Please add the code of rendered page, which imports component EventDetails.

As mentioned by the sahilatahar, it is probably related to next.js revalidatePath and redirect functions are unreachable, but if you include them in the try-catch part, they will not work. So far there are two solutions I have run into:

Using them in finally block.
Taking them outside of the action function, and use them in your pages/components after calling and getting a response from the server.

If you choose the first solution, you might wanna add a flag not to revalidate or redirect unless the response is successful.
Also you might want to use router.refresh() instead of revalidate since you are not storing any cache. See the Next.js documentation for that. router.refresh() will allow you to keep the states but still refetch the data.
For the above examples you might wanna take a look at the below q/a:
NextJS 13 revalidatePath() working for created comments but not for created posts

I can suggest to return you api response and update you app state and then navigate to other page using useRouter hook.
Form Submit function
const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>){
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    const apiResponse = await uploadChangedEventDetailsWithId(formData)

    // Update you state

    // Navigate
    router.push("/event") // <------- change with your route
  }

"use server"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache"

export async function uploadChangedEventDetails(
    eventId: number,
    formData: FormData
) {
    const rawFormData = {
        title: formData.get("title"),
        description: formData.get("description"),
    }
    console.log(rawFormData)

    try {
        // post the changed data (this works. I've truncated the api string here)
        let data = await fetch(`http://.../events/${eventId}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            cache: "no-store",
            body: JSON.stringify(rawFormData),
        })
        let json = await data.json()
        console.log(json)

        return json  // <-------- return data
    } catch (e) {
        return { message: `Unable to update event with ID: ${eventId}` }
    }

    // It not working it is unreachable code.
    revalidatePath("/")
    redirect(`/events/${eventId}`)
}



I handle them using  @tanstack/react-query. The initial hooks you want to begin with are useQuery and useMutation and you are good to go. useQuery(for GET requests that do not change the content of database) will accept a key which can be invalidated when a Mutation(for POST, PATCH and DELETE) requests are succeded.
For simple example I have two hooks for getting and adding users.

useFetchUsers.js



import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchUsers = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get("/users");
  return result.data.data;
};

export const useFetchUsers = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["user"],
    queryFn: fetchUsers,
  });
};




useAddUser.js



import axios from "axios";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const addUser = async (user) => {
    const route = "/user"
    const result = await axios.post(route, user);
    return result.data;
};
  
export const useAddUser = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    return useMutation({
      mutationFn: (user)=>addCompanyUser(user),
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["users"] });
      },
    });
  };
  



You can get the data by
{data, isLoading, isError} = useFetchUsers(); 

And onSubmit of the form
const addUserMutation = useAddUser();
const handleSubmit = (data) => {
  addUserMutation.mutate(data, {
  onSuccess: () => {
    console.log("Added successfully");
  },
  onError: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
}

With large number of api endpoints, It will make revalidating the paths easier.
